# cache token pin for decode x509 certificate c#

Tags: c#, decode, x509certificate

I have a .NET (c#) application which uses the x509Certificate2 in the 'my' Certificate Store, originally coming from an eToken device.

When I use the certificate (to decrypt data or use it as a clientcert ), it will ask for the device PIN once.

Now, I have multiple processes, that all use the certificate. Each of these processes will request the device PIN. (the cache seems to be per process).

Is there an easy way around this? Can I 'cache' it somewhere, so that every process can access the token without requesting the PIN over and over again?
Or how can i pass Pin ?

Comment: You can pass the PIN using Win32 methods. Not sure if it's possible with .NET classes, though, but in our SecureBlackbox .NET this is possible. Or you can use PKCS#11 interface, then you always provide a pin in code.